# Get file content to json/geojson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geojson

I really don't understand my problem :
I have geojson files, I need to get the content and return a valid variable.

My test :

```
//this works
var obj_valid = {"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "14001", "nom": "val1" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 0.301, 49.371 ], xxx , [ 0.301, 49.371 ] ] ] ] } }]};

//doesn't work
var obj_fail = $.getJSON("geojson/com/14001.json");
```

I would like to return the same content that what is in my first var "obj_valid". I tried $.getJSON, $.ajax, $.getScript but without success, the output is different :

[image]

What is my mistake ??

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 3):

`$.getJSON` is an ajax request and is asynchrounous. It doesn't return data , it returns a promise.

You need to consume the response data in a success or done callback

```
$.getJSON("geojson/com/14001.json", function(responseData){
   // do something with responseData
});

// OR
 $.getJSON("geojson/com/14001.json").done(function(responseData){
   // do something with responseData
});
```

See [$.getJSON docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be like this

```
var obj_fail = {};
$.getJSON("geojson/com/14001.json")
 .done(function(data){
    obj_fail = data;
 });
```

Hope this helps!